# Validate that the sum of the part is equal to the total with parent/children records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, associations

I have 2 models:

```
Invoice has_many :lines

Line belongs_to :invoice
```

I want to ensure that the sum of the `Line` for a given `Invoice` match the total of the related `Invoice`.

I've tried this:

```
validate :total_amount
def total_amount
    inv_id = self.invoice_id
    target_amount = Invoice.find(inv_id).total
    total_lines = Line.where(invoice_id: inv_id).sum(:line_value)

    errors.add(:total, " should be lower or equal to the total amount of the invoice") if total_lines > target_amount
end
```

But

1. it doesn't work for new objects (just updates)
2. even for updates it systematically throws an error

I've also seen a question talking about AssociatedValidator, but I haven't been able to grasp how to use that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be interpreting it wrong, but if `total` is a column in the `invoices` table, I suggest removing it. Instead, have it as a method and have the method add up the `Line` prices plus any adjustments. Otherwise, you have duplication in the database. And that way you won't need to validate anything anyway :)

On a more general note, adding validations on associated models in `ActiveRecord` is not working very well. In some cases it's almost impossible, in other - pretty hard to get right. I think you've seen that it goes wrong easily. I suggest avoiding it and trying to design your database so that you won't need to (having `Invoice#total` as a method in this case).

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what exactly you want to validate, since your example is different from what you were describing prior to that.

I think something like this should work, using a [before_add callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Association+callbacks):

```
class Invoice < AR::Base
  has_many :lines, :before_add => :validate_total

  def validate_total(invoice, line)
    totals = invoice.lines.sum(:line_value)

    if totals + line.line_value > invoice.total
      invoice.errors.add(:total, " should be lower or equal to the total amount of the invoice")
      return false # I think you can alternatively raise an exception here
  end
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It took a little while to find an question/answer to a problem that cropped up using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. But the answer just said *It's hard, if not impossible!*. `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is a somewhat complicated approach, but it works - unless you are trying to validate a model based on a calculation of the children model. I may have found a way to to overcome the calculation problem.

I'm working on a web based double entry accounting application that *had* the following basic models;

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :splits
  has_many :entries, through: :splits
end

class Entry < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :splits, -> {order(:account_id)}, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :entry

  validate  :balanced?
end

class Split < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :entry, inverse_of: :splits
  belongs_to :account

  validates_associated :account
  validates_associated :entry
end
```

Entries(transactions) must have at least two Splits that the sum of the Amount attribute(or Debits/Credits) in the Splits must equal 0. I though the `validate  :balanced?` would take care of it, but an apparent Javascript error allowed an unbalance entry. I've yet to track the bug down, but since the Entry was unbalanced, I could not update it since `valid?` does not work (returns false) on new Splits that I tried to add.

The ledger `accepts_nested_attributes_for` form has quit a bit of Javascript that is not supposed to allow an unbalanced transaction to be submitted. Balanced? did not set an error on create, but its there on update. My approach to fixing it is not used validations that don't work, but to rely on a method called in conjunction with `@entry.update(entry_params)`:

```
class Entry < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :splits, -> {order(:account_id)}, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :entry

  # validate  :balanced? # took this out since its after the fact, balanced? method can still be called

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :splits, 
    :reject_if =>  proc { |att| att[:amount].to_i.zero? && att['account_id'].to_i.zero?},
    allow_destroy: true

    def valid_params?(params)
      split_sum = 0
      params_hash = params.to_h
      params_hash[:splits_attributes].each{|k,s| split_sum += s[:amount].to_i if s[:_destroy].to_i.zero?}
      unless split_sum.zero?
        errors.add(:amount, "Unbalanced: debits, credits must balance")
        return false
      else
        return true
      end
    end
  end
end

# update action from Entry Controller

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @entry.valid_params?(entry_params) && @entry.update(entry_params)
      format.html { redirect_to account_path(session[:current_acct]), notice: 'Entry was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @entry }
    else
      # ... errr
    end
  end
end
```

Again, this in nothing more than validating the params verses the model validation that does not work for this condition.

This may be about same as answer 2, but not using a callback, just calling in controller